# parallel build not working with release plugin

Tags: maven

Maven `-T` not working with release plugin

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you mean by `maven does recognizes correct no. of threads used`? Do you know exactly what `-T 1C` means? `mvn deploy` have you tried it? and what is `mvn release`? What do you mean exactly by: `While using it with release simply fails with..`? Can you show the exact commands you have use? Does your build correctly work ? How many modules do you have? Do you have unit tests?

Comment: @khmarbaise Added errors and testing done. Have read about parallel build support with maven 3.x, but have only seen its implementation with install phase

Comment: Which  Maven version do you use? And which JDK do you use? You have not answered the questions about: How many modules do you have ?

Comment: Can you please show full pom files etc. and answer the questions...

Answer (score 1):

I start to write as answer cause the comment area is too limited.

The mentioned point 2. must have failed with an error cause `-T` requires parameters (Missing argument for option: T`)

Furthermore the given call `release:prepare release:perform clean install deploy` is simply wrong.

Let us begin with some basics. A combination of `install` and `deploy` shows that there is a misunderstanding about the [Maven life cycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

So using `install` only makes sense if you want to install the artifacts only into your local repository (`$HOME/.m2/repository`) to be consumed by other project on the same machine which is usually not the case.

Using `deploy` (which includes `install`) is used to upload the created artifacts into a remote repository (like Nexus, Artifactory) which is in corporate environments the case.

Based on the output I can see that you are using extremely old plugin versions like `maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:` this version is ten years old. Furthermore I see the usage of a `sources` goal which is used to resolve sources of the dependencies where I would ask: Why do you need that?

The mentioned point 1:

```
mvn deploy -U -T 1C -DskipTests -Dmaven.install.skip=true
```

this shows that you have not understand the purpose of `install` and `deploy` phase cause the `install` phase is needed to install the artifacts and `deploy` phase will transfer them to the remote repository which means it does not make sense to skip the install part (I doubt that this will work). Furthermore using `-U` only would make sense if you have `SNAPSHOT` dependencies otherwise this is waste of time.

The usage of `-DskipTests` gives me the impression you seemed to have long running unit tests (or they might be integration tests instead?)...

To make a release with Maven you should go:

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform
```

Nothing else. Based on the supplemental parameters you are giving during a release it looks like your pom files seemed to be not in optimal state.

The given option `-DcheckModificationExcludeList=pom.xml` looks from my point of view like a problem cause usually you don't need that and furthermore during a release the `pom.xml` will be changed (the version) so from that point of view it does not make sense. The modification is to check if something not checked in before running a release..(The whole thing looks not concise to me).

Based on the error message you have given:

```
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
```

I bet your maven-compiler-plugin version is very old? Which version do you use?

I recommend to use an up-to-date version of maven-release-plugin which is hopefully correctly configured in your pom file (which I can't tell you cause you haven't showed the full pom files).
Also I recommend to use a most recent version of Maven and check all plugins (using most recent versions) and in particular the configuration of the appropriate plugins if the configuration is correct and really needed and fulfills your needs.